# Why does the "@IsGranted" annotation does not work if I also configure security using "security.yaml"?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security

I have a controller, where I use the `@IsGranted(IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY)` annotation to allow all users to access, and I also have a `security.yaml`.

But I the annotation  does not seem to work.

**Controller**

```
    /**
     * @Route("/example",name="app_example")
     * @IsGranted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY")
     */
    public function example(): RedirectResponse
    {
        /// omit
    }
```

**security.yaml**

```
  access_control:
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

When I access `/example`, I'm requested to login.

I know I can manage by moving `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` to `security.yaml` but I want to know the way to use annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@IsGranted()` (from SensioFrameworkExtraBundle) is checked on an event that comes **after** Symfony Security access control.

Since you have contradictory configurations (your main security configuration demands authentication on **all** routes, and your the annotation on your controller simply says "no authentication on this route"), the main security configuration "wins".

If you want to have security configuration both in the configuration file **and** as annotations, the configuration shouldn't overlap and contradict each other.

If they conflict, for the `@IsGranted()` annotations to work they can be **more restrictive** than the main security configuration, but not **more open**.